# submitting hadoop-streaming jobs: yarn or hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

What's the difference between submitting a hadoop-streaming job using the `yarn jar` command and using the `hadoop jar` command?

This is from the [current documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html):

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar \
  -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 \
  -input myInputDirs \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper /bin/cat \
  -reducer /usr/bin/wc
```

But this command could be done just as well with:

```
yarn jar hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar \
  -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 \
  -input myInputDirs \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper /bin/cat \
  -reducer /usr/bin/wc
```

If the two commands are equivillent (as I think they are), which is preferred, and why?

Comment: There is no difference between these two statements. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180142/what-difference-between-execute-a-map-reduce-job-using-hadoop-and-java-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equal if your MapReduce framework is YARN. If not, `hadoop jar` will run your jar file with MRv1 and `yarn jar` will run your jar by YARN(MRv2).

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I thought it would switch to YARN automatically. Thanks for pointing this out!