# Commands for executing JAR file containing mapreduce programming on hadoop in Singleton Mode

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, jar

I have Hadoop setup in Stand-Alone Mode on Ubuntu.
I have JAR file with MapReduce program: runner.JAR in /home/ubuntu folder
package for JAR file: mypackage3
I have input file: demo.csv in /home/ubuntu folder

I want to execute this jar file with demo.csv as an input.

I have used below commands to copy Hadoop's configuration files into it:

```
mkdir ~/input
cp /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/*.xml ~/input
```

Can you please tell me how to execute this MapReduce program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what difference between execute a map-reduce job using hadoop and java command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180142/what-difference-between-execute-a-map-reduce-job-using-hadoop-and-java-command)